# Multivariate data for LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, keras

Please help to understand how to prepare multivariate data for LSTM in Keras.
Example - there is three features data

```
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
x3 y3 z3
x4 y4 z4
x5 y5 z5
```

(numbers is chronology - 1 is earliest and 5 is latests and so on)
For LSTM in Keras I need to transform this data to 3 dimensional tensor form
(samples, timesteps, features). If I want 3 timesteps which of transformation is correct

1

```
[
[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3]],
[[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3],[x4,y4,z4]],
[[x3,y3,z3],[x4,y4,z4],[x5,y5,z5]]
]
```

Or

2

```
[
[[x1,x2,x3],[y1,y2,y3],[z1,z2,z3]],
[[x2,x3,x4],[y2,y3,y4],[z2,z3,z4]],
[[x3,x4,x5],[y3,y4,y5],[z3,z4,z5]]
]
```

?

Thanks for any help

Comment: First one is the correct one. As you mentioned the last axis is the features axis so it must have all the features in it and that's exactly what the first form is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really very helpful